# Different TechLists on same NFC-Tag

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

Why do I receive different TechLists when I read **the same** NFC-Tag with different devices with this piece of code:

```
Tag l_DiscoveredTag = ...;
l_DiscoveredTag.getTechList();
```

Samsung Galaxy S5:

1. NfcA
2. Ndef

Samsung Galaxy S7:

1. NfcA
2. MifareUltralight

The tag should have the same TechList on everey device or not?

Answer (score 0):

Because the tech types are typically a combination of low- and highlevel functionality. This is a good thing; you can select the tech type you prefer.

For example NDEF is a payload which has standardized storage on various tag types, like mifare ultralight.